# How to extract texts from images in a folder

Tags: tesseract

My laptop is Ubuntu, I have a folder called testdata which contains lots of jpg images, I want to know how to run Tesseract on all these images and save outputs to another folder e.g. "testresult". Outputs can be a single txt file contains extract texts from all images. Or, it can be one txt file for one image extracted text only.

For a single image, the command line I know is tesseract test_01.jpg test_01

Could anyone help me please?